# Determine similarity in percentages between species A and B, A and C, and B and C

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, proteins, protein-structure

[image]

The chart above is a graphic that shows the amino acid sequence differences between different organisms for a protein keratin.

The question I am required to answer begins as, **"Keratin is made up of about 450 amino acids. Determine the similarity in percentages between species A and B, A and C, and B and C. Explain how amino acid sequences can be used in determining how closely related two species are."**

My initial solution to **finding the percentages** is dividing the respective differences in the chart above by 450. Then, subtract that number by 100, and hence, find the similarity percentage. For example, for species A and B, I would divide 4 by 450, resulting in 0.89%. I would next subtract this percentage from 100%, resulting in 99.11% similarity. Is this the correct procedure?

My initial solution to **explaining how amino acid sequences can be used to determine how closely related two species are** is as follows: The larger the difference in amino acid sequences between two species, the less closely related two species are. Is this explanation correct as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step number one is correct, but note that there are several similarity (or alternatively distance) measures. What you choose is the simplest and most intuitive one and it a good one without any other assumption or explanation given.

Step number two is also correct, **if** the similarity is a good proxy for when the last common ancestor between two species is in time, which in this case should be.